# laravel mysql column for tablename

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a laravel mysql query to select a column named title and **the table name as Source**

```
$query = DB::select('select title, "'.$table_name.'" as source from ' . $table_name);
```

but this returns an array, and I want to perform union query for the above query. So I adopted the **laravel DB::table()**

```
DB::table($table_name)->select('title, "'.$table_name.'" as source')
```

But the above query returns an error **unknown column name**.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '"tablename"' in 'field list' (SQL: select `title`, `"tablename"` as `source` from `tablename`)

I just want to add another field named source and put the table name in all rows.

I repeat the same for number of tables and finally sort them before rendering. 
Please help me out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would suggest binding as laravel documentaion says but it won't work in your case because you are trying to bind table names

Comment: maybe this works $select = "select title, ".$table_name." as source from " . $table_name;   then DB::select($select);

Comment: It worked. But still returns an array so I can't perform union query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27637515/8002326) helped me.

```
$row = sprintf('"%s" AS source', $tablename);
$query = DB::table($tablename)->select('title', DB::raw($row));
```